# find out where one react component is used?

Tags: reactjs

is there a way to find out where a react component is used in other components?

for example:

navbar components is used in app.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Navbar = () => {
    return <div>this is Navbar</div>;
};

export default Navbar;
```

```
import React from 'react'; import Navbar from './Navbar';

const App = () => {return (<div><Navbar /></div>); };

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3):

There's two ways to find:

1. [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi) extension (recommended) tool for debugging. It has a Search bar (text or/regex/)

[image]

2. Most of IDE/Code editors now days has the ability to help you find out component usage

Cheers and I hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Most IDEs should be able to find `references` to the component.
Otherwise, a simple search should find it.

Comment: yeah there is a search icon in sidebar of vscode that i didn't use that before, thank you

Comment: In vscode, right click on the component name and use `find all references`, keybindings differ on OSes. :)